# PHP Get JSON data from API with access token

Tags: php, json

I've tried writing a code to get JSON data from API like this

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.jakarta.go.id/v1/kota/?format=json";
$ch = curl_init();
$accesstoken = "my_token";
$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: OAuth '.$accesstoken;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
?>
```

but not working and i get NULL data. please help me :)

Comment: Try a `var_dump($result, true)` first, to see what content do you get. It might be an error message in HTML....

Comment: Have you tried to call the API from other tools with the exact parameters? Because when i tried to call the API with query_string `format=json` it showed a response but with error "Parameter unknown" on the message

Comment: Technically the oAuth specifications say you should be issued a `Bearer` token. Are you sure the authorisation header shouldn't be `Authorization: Bearer my_token`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me.

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.jakarta.go.id/v1/kota');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization:my_token'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```